# Restore deleted files using Dropbox API

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

I was searching for a way to use Dropbox API to restore my files and Google brought me here.

**First of all, a bit about my situation:**

My computer got a virus that rename all of my files (idk if its recognized as rename or delete on Dropbox) and they are all synced to Dropbox. I want to download all my original files using Dropbox API.

As i can see on web interface, I can download them individually but I got like thousand files so I couldn't do it.

**My problem:**

I used Python API wrapper to work with Dropbox API. I first fetched all of my files and tried to get all of their revisions but the original files are not included in revision list.

Then I tried to list all of my files including deleted files and I can see my original files listed. I tried to download them using download endpoint but it returned `File not found` error. Has anyone bumped into something similar? How can I solve this issue?

**My code snippet:**

```
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('token is intentionally hidden')
print dbx.users_get_current_account()
for entry in dbx.files_list_folder('', recursive = False, include_deleted = True).entries:
  if (isinstance(entry, dropbox.files.FileMetadata) or isinstance(entry, dropbox.files.DeletedMetadata)):
    if not entry.name.endswith('cerber2'):
      print "name: ", entry.name, "| path: ", entry.path_lower 
      print repr(entry)
      try:
        meta, resp = dbx.files_download(entry.path_lower)
      except dropbox.exceptions.ApiError as e:
        print e.user_message_text
      print "-" * 80
```

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203343359-How-to-Undelete-a-File-via-the-API?page=1#community_comment_210217666 ]

First, can you post the full error you're getting?

Also, at a glance, your call to [`files_restore`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_restore) looks wrong, since that method requires two parameters, and you're only passing in one.

Comment: Oh im sorry, I pasted wrong code, I just updated my post, I actually used files_download() instead of files_restore()

Comment: I'm actually getting `ApiError` exception, I expected to be able to download deleted files because I can do so on Dropbox web interface.

Comment: Can you print `e` though? There should be a more useful error. Also, I'm not sure why you're calling [`files_download`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_download) twice, but if you're trying to download an older (not deleted) version of a file, you'll need to specify a `rev`, e.g., as returned by [`files_list_revisions`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_list_revisions).

Comment: I thought so too because my original files appear in previous versions section on Dropbox web interface, however when I tried to call `files_list_revisions`, they are not listed. They are only shown when I specified `include_deleted = True`. I meant only 1 download, I just edited my post. There is no useful error message, when I caught the HTTP package, server responded with 409 "File not found".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been scratching my head over this exact problem this afternoon, to try and restore the state of a friend's Dropbox which got hit by the same ransomware.  I don't know whether you're still in need of a solution, but in a nutshell, here's the state of play.

In Dropbox API V2, every file has a unique ID.  This is persisted across deletes, renames, moves, etc.  This will be key to fixing this problem, as Dropbox tracks file history by file path, so as soon as the ransomware renamed your files, the option of simply rolling back your files programmatically was lost.  To make things even more difficult, fetch a directory listing with `include_deleted` set to True and you'll notice that Dropbox don't include file IDs in the metadata for deletions.  If they did, this would be a breeze.

So, here's what to do instead:

1. Fetch a list of files, as normal.
2. Split that list of files into two lists, existing files and those that have been deleted:

   deleted = list(filter(lambda file: isinstance(file, dropbox.files.DeletedMetadata), files.entries))

(where `files` is an instance of `dropbox.files.ListFolderResult`)

3. Here's where things get a bit hairy when it comes to API calls.  For each of the deleted files, you need to fetch a list of revisions, using `dropbox.Dropbox.files_list_revisions`.  Take the first revision, which will be the newest, and store its ID alongside the file path.  This is how we get an ID for a deleted file.
4. Now that we (hopefully) have an ID for each deleted file in your folder/Dropbox, all that's left to do is to match up those IDs with the IDs of the existing encrypted .cerber2 files.  Once you've done that, you'll have a mapping between the encrypted .cerber2 file and the original, decrypted file stored in your Dropbox history.  Simply restore the old file and delete the files created by the virus.

I've purposefully left the actual implementation in code up to you, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Hm this is a bit tricky i guess. Thank you for your answer. However I think Dropbox API should improve to make it easier to use.

Comment: `revisions = dbx.files_list_revisions(entry.path_lower)` where entry is a deleted file. I got empty revisions. Did i do it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks James Scholes, Exactly what I was looking for.
Solution works very well with the files, but this does not work for folders, Since there is no versions/revisions for a folder. In this case any other way that I can undelete the folder??.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Sample code in Java:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DbxException {

    String userLocale = Locale.getDefault().toString();
    DbxRequestConfig requestConfig = new DbxRequestConfig("examples-authorize", userLocale);

    DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(requestConfig, AUTH_TOKEN);
    FullAccount account = client.users().getCurrentAccount();

    Set<String> folderNames;

    SearchResult result = client.files().searchBuilder("/Pankaj", "*.cerber3").withMaxResults(1000L).withMode(SearchMode.FILENAME).start();
    folderNames = new HashSet<>(result.getMatches().size());
    for (SearchMatch match : result.getMatches()){
        FileMetadata fileMetadata = (FileMetadata) match.getMetadata();
        String path = fileMetadata.getPathLower();
        folderNames.add(path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/")));
    }
    for(String path : folderNames){
        processDirectory(path, client);
    }
}

static void processDirectory(String dirName, DbxClientV2 client) throws DbxException {
    ListFolderResult result = client.files().listFolderBuilder(dirName).withIncludeDeleted(true).start();

    while (true) {
        for (Metadata metadata : result.getEntries()) {
        if(metadata instanceof DeletedMetadata){
                String filePath = metadata.getPathLower();
                if(filePath.endsWith(".doc") || filePath.endsWith(".docx") || filePath.endsWith(".pdf")){
                    List<FileMetadata> revisions = client.files().listRevisions(filePath).getEntries();
                    if(revisions.size()>0) {
                        FileMetadata revision = revisions.get(0);
                        System.out.println("Deleted File: " + filePath + ", " + revision.getClientModified() + ", Id:" + revision.getId());
                        revision.getRev();
                        client.files().restore(filePath, revision.getRev());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (!result.getHasMore()) {
            break;
        }

        result = client.files().listFolderContinue(result.getCursor());
    }

}
```