# How do i list deleted files from the Dropbox API? C# MVC

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, dropbox-api

i'm working with a web aplication in which i'm using the Dropbox API, but i'm struggling trying to find out how to get deleted folders or files from the Recycle bin. 
Can anyone help me out?

i'm using this line to get Folder/Files from root.

`var list = await dbx.Files.ListFolderAsync(string.Empty);`

Could inserting the Recycle bin url work?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38912264/restore-deleted-files-using-dropbox-api) out: it should answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [the Dropbox API v2 .NET](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet) SDK, you can set `includeDeleted=true` when calling [`ListFolderAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderAsync_1.htm) to request deleted files as well.